# Python: what is wrong with this function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

this code is supposed to count the total of listed items price after it checks if the items are available on the stock (stock variable), I want to know why I doesn't print anything.

```
    shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total=0
    for i in food:
        if stock[i]>0:
            total+=prices[i]
    return total    
    print total
compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your print needs to be before the return statement:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total=0
    for i in food:
        if stock[i]>0:
            total+=prices[i]    
    print total
    return total
```

Comment: another question, shouldn't it prints (4+1.5+3 )= 8.5 instead of 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

If running in an IDE you will need to use `print`

```
print compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

The `print total` is `unreachable` after the return statement.

So either forget about the `print` or put the `print` *before* the `return`

Comment: another question, shouldn't it prints (4+1.5+3 )= 8.5 instead of 5.5?

Comment: No, there is no apples in stock so `if stock[i]>0:` will be `False` for apples and the price won't be added so 5.5 is correct

Comment: I know that there is no apple in the stock that's why I said it should be 8.5, if the apple was in stock it would've been 10.5 !

Comment: why didn't you add "pear"? it is available in the stock!

Comment: where do you see `pear` in the shopping list?